# If bool x = FALSE, how can I force if(x) to evaluate to TRUE?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security

This is something of an obtuse question, but I'm trying to write unit tests for the following method:

```
+ (BOOL)alwaysTrue:(NSError **)error {
    BOOL alwaysFalse = FALSE;
       if (alwaysFalse) {
           if (error) {
               //Assign a value to error
           }
           return FALSE;
       }
       return TRUE;
}
```

And I'm trying to determine if there is some way from outside the method to manipulate it such that `alwaysFalse` can be assigned a value of `TRUE` and the method can be made to return `FALSE`

Comment: This may be a simple answer, but you could of course set alwaysFalse = TRUE instead, if it is assignable.

Comment: But, without modifying that source directly, how would you go about doing that? (This is the exercise - the method is written as intended)

Comment: Is that the real method? Why? The `if` statement will never be true. It will always return `TRUE`. Why not simply have a one-line implementation: `return TRUE;`? BTW - `BOOL` should only use `YES` and `NO`. not `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Orders from above dictated that the method be written like that (why? beats me.) That is indeed the real method.

Comment: Not for a local variable in anything short of architecture-specific assembler, no. You have to get either the variable or its value outside of that method somehow. What is the unit test you need to write?

Answer (score 0):

If `x = false`, then `x || true` will always evaluate to `true`. If this is how you have to unit test though, I bet there is a better way to write your original function. Post it if you're looking for suggestions for improvement.

Comment: The code in the question is, line for line, the original function, written to the specifications given for it. I agree that the method is ridiculous, but I put on my good little soldier helmet and wrote it as ordered.

The mission now is to find some way to break it (without re-writing it)

Comment: I see - sort of, haha. In that case, no, the method will always return `FALSE`. The scoping rules for `alwaysFalse` indicate that no "global" variable, even with the same name, will override it.